# how to render different layout & json data in one action of conroller in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, layout

I am new to Rails.

I want to render layout(.html.erb file) as well as json data from action of controller.
How can I perform it?

Can I render both of them in single action? how?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what `respond_to` is for. From the [Rails Action Controller guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#rendering-xml-and-json-data):

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render xml: @users}
      format.json { render json: @users}
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: In my app, there is one view on which by clicking on button data which are in textbox is passed through json to action of controller. And in the same controller I want to display matched result on another view file(.html.erb) using other action. How can I do that? Thanks.